# Updating/Saving Information to MySQL Database from Datagrid MDI

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview, mdi

I've got a bit of an odd one, I've been looking online but cannot find anything specific to my issue. Hopefully someone could help me.

I have a VB.Net 2012 application that reads information from MySQL. The reading is fine and it populates correctly but I am having trouble working out how to save changes back.

The information is displayed from a DataTable into a DataGridView. The application is an MDI application and at anygiven point there could be more than one TableEditor Form Open as a Child.

This is my information loading function:

```
    Public Function get_SQL(ByVal SQLquery As String) As DataTable
    Try
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim myData As New DataTable
        Dim MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection

        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & sqlServer & ";" _
            & "user id=" & sqlUsername & ";" _
            & "password=" & sqlPassword & ";" _
            & "database=" & sqlDatabase

        MysqlConn.Open()
        myCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
        myCommand.CommandText = SQLquery
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        myAdapter.Fill(myData)
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
        Return (myData)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Main.lblStatus.Text = "SQL Connection Error"
        errMsg = ex.ToString
        errForm = "SQL Connection"
        errWrite()
    End Try
End Function
```

And the information is loaded into the child form on load like this:

```
    Private Sub SQLeditor_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ToolStrip1.Visible = False
    Select Case sqlclick
        Case Is = "Office Details"
            SQLdata = get_SQL(qryOffice)
        Case Is = "School Details"
            SQLdata = get_SQL(qrySchools)
        Case Is = "ICT Staff"
            SQLdata = get_SQL(qryITstaff)
        Case Else
            ToolStrip1.Visible = True
    End Select
    dgvEditor.DataSource = SQLdata
End Sub
```

SQLdata is a global variable "Public SQLdata As DataTable"

So I want to create a new Function that will save any changes back to the SQL database. As I am using the same global variable to populate a single form with multiple instances that can exist simultaneously I need to work out how to pass the information from the DataGridView or something along those lines and I'm stuck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution in the end and thought I'd post it incase anyone else comes across the same issue.

I eventually settled on only having a single editable window open at a time using code like this:

```
Public sqlEditForm As SQLeditor
If issql = True Then
            If sqlEditForm Is Nothing OrElse sqlEditForm.IsDisposed Then
                sqlEditForm = New SQLeditor
                sqlEditForm.MdiParent = Main
                sqlEditForm.Show()
            Else
                Dim reply As DialogResult
                reply = MsgBox("An existing edit window is already active, do you want to close the existing instance and create a new one?" & vbCrLf & "Any unsaved changes will be lost?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Existing Window Detected")
                Select Case reply
                    Case Is = vbYes
                        sqlEditForm.Close()
                        sqlEditForm = New SQLeditor
                        sqlEditForm.MdiParent = Main
                        sqlEditForm.Show()
                    Case Is = vbNo
                        sqlEditForm.Show()
                    Case Is = vbCancel

                End Select
            End If
```

And then just saving a single instance of the data from the data adapter.

```
    Public Sub save_SQL()
    Try
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim cmdb = New MySqlCommandBuilder(myAdapter)

        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & sqlServer & ";" _
            & "user id=" & sqlUsername & ";" _
            & "password=" & sqlPassword & ";" _
            & "database=" & sqlDatabase

        MysqlConn.Open()

        Select Case sqlclick
            Case Is = "Office Details"
                myAdapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(qryOffice, MysqlConn)
            Case Is = "School Details"
                myAdapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(qrySchools, MysqlConn)
            Case Is = "ICT Staff"
                myAdapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(qryITstaff, MysqlConn)
            Case Is = "SQL Editor"
                myAdapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(qrycustom, MysqlConn)
            Case Else
        End Select
        myAdapter.Update(SQLdata)

        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Main.lblStatus.Text = "SQL Connection Error"
        errMsg = ex.ToString
        errForm = "SQL Connection"
        errWrite()
    End Try
End Sub
```

It shouldn't be that hard to adapt the same system into a multi-MDI model but I don't think I have the need for it.